# How to get form content from HTML with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Sorry, i almost desperate to solve the problem. I'v been search the solution for 2 weeks.

I have a javascript syntax to find IP Address. The content of input text is from javascript and I want to define it as a variable in PHP.

```
window.onload = function() {
      findIP(addIP);
    }
    function findIP(onNewIP) { //  onNewIp - your listener function for new IPs
      var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection; //compatibility for firefox and chrome
      var pc = new myPeerConnection({iceServers: []}),
        noop = function() {},
        localIPs = {},
        ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
        key;

      function ipIterate(ip) {
        if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
        localIPs[ip] = true;
      }
      pc.createDataChannel(""); //create a bogus data channel
      pc.createOffer(function(sdp) {
        sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
          if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
          line.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
        });
        pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
      }, noop); // create offer and set local description
      pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) { //listen for candidate events
        if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
        ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
      };
    }


    function addIP(ip) {
      console.log('got ip: ', ip);
      document.getElementById("get_IP").value=ip;
    }


    var ipaddr = findIP(addIP);

    </script>

<html>
<body>
<form name="getgot" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="get_IP" id="get_IP">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

how can I echo it as variable in PHP ? please help

Comment: You can send the found IP address by AJAX to a PHP script or you send the `<form>` to a PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the variable `ip` in javascript (on any page), here is one easy way to turn that Javascript variable into a PHP variable:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['ip'])) {
    $IP = $_GET['ip'];
}

else {
    echo '
    <script>
    if (typeof ip !== 'undefined') {
        window.location.href += '?ip='+ip;
    }
    </script>
    ';
}
?>
```

This PHP script will:

1. Check if the parameter `?ip=` exists in the URL
2. If the parameter exists, a PHP variable `$IP` will be created with the same value
3. If the parameter doesn't exist, a javascript will check that the variable `ip` exists
4. If the variable exists, the window will reload with the parameter `?ip=`

If neither the URL parameter nor the variable exist, nothing happens.